# Push Notifications Azure Mobile Service (Self Hosted)

Tags: azure, push-notification, hosting, azure-mobile-services

I am looking into creating a Azure Mobile Service project and I also want to send push notifications to iOS and Android apps (Xamarin).

I don't have an Azure account and I am wondering if there is an easy way to self host the Azure Mobile Service project and use all its functionality?! Or do I have to host it on the Azure servers?

Thanks for you help!

Answer (score 1):

Azure Mobile Services uses [Notification Hubs](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/services/notification-hubs/) for push, which is an Azure service that requires a subscription.